# How to make a pairing and mode button on a remote control receiver

Tags: microcontroller, rf, remote-control

I'm working on a remote control project and have come across many different RF receiver/transmitter modules.  Many have a pairing/mode button on the receiver that serves to pair the receiver and transmitter and to choose which mode the transmitter is in, momentary, latching, toggle, etc. Is this feature done with a microcontroller? Can I buy the chip preprogrammed or do I need to use something like Arduino? How could I duplicate this feature on a receiver that does not have it? Thanks.

Has feature:
[image]

Doesn't have feature:
[image]

Comment: Those modules seem to be pure data links, so it is up to your MCU or whatever to send something that contains a device identification and make the receiver react to data or learn its ID.

Comment: What you think pairing brings to the party and what it actually might do could be poles apart. You are asking for an undefined feature, so try and narrow down that feature into a list of technical requirements. Short version: please state what pairing does.

Comment: @Andy aka The pairing makes it so only a specific transmitter is understood by the receiver.

Comment: Using a microcontroller is the clear way to do this AND you will need to use a micro on the devices shown towards the bottom of your question.